# Как осуществить многоуровневое наследование UserControl от других UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, наследование

Я хочу создать "семейство" `Alert`'ов (окошечек-уведомлений), которые, собственно, будут просто уведомлять пользователя о чём-то и не только.

Для этих целей могут понадобиться различные `Alert`'ы. Допустим один `Alert` предназначен для простого вывода уведомляющего текста. Другой играет роль **confirm**'a, как в `JavaScript` - пользователю предоставиться выбор между двумя действиями: *Продолжить* или *Выйти*.

С какой бы целью они не создавались у этих `Alert`'ов есть общие свойства. Допустим, выводимый текст, обработчики и т.д.

Общие свойства у меня будет содержать **производный** класс `Alert`:

```
public partial class Alert : UserControl, IAlert
{
    public static DependencyProperty MainTextProperty;
    static Alert()
    {
        MainTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MainText", typeof(string), typeof(Alert));
    }

    public string MainText
    { 
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(MainTextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MainTextProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public virtual void Show() // метод для анимации появления
    {

    }
}
```

Этот класс представляет обычное окошечко-уведомление, выводящее текст, содержащий какую-то информацию для пользователя.

Чтобы выводить другой "важности" информацию, я хочу чтобы у этого `Alert` появился   заголовок. Этот класс менять не резон, так как где этот заголовок просто не нужен в использовании. Поэтому я создаю новый производный от `Alert` `HeaderedAlert`:

```
public partial class HeaderedAlert : Alert, IHeaderedAlert
{
    public static DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty;
    static HeaderedAlert()
    {
        HeaderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderedAlert));
    }
    public string HeaderText
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Но я не могу использовать `DependencyProperty` базового `Alert`. А ведь могут быть более "модифицированные" `Alert`'ы. И они должны использовать и свойства `HeaderedAlert`. Но не могут.

Как можно это "обойти"?

Comment: Какой то странный у вас базовый контрол. Где например `InitializeComponent();`? И почему регистрация проходит через конструктор? Напишите в студии `propdp` и нажмите TAB, он вам создаст полноценное свойство, вам только задать имя, тип и класс. А по поводу наследования, ну вот допустим мой [основной контрол с одним свойством](https://pastebin.com/w4F1xUxc), далее создал простой класс и унаследовал его, там же создал еще одно свойство и в итоге получил [это](https://pastebin.com/WY3UzkpY).  Ну и как видите все [успешно работает](https://pastebin.com/qs41W7dB). Так чего же вы пытаетесь обойти?

Comment: Также `public virtual void Show() // метод для анимации появления` - тут явно бессмысленна, ибо анимации задаются в триггерах, а не через код. Старайтесь отделить все стили, анимации и тд. в XAML, код лишь выполняет логику необходимую для отображения, минимальную.